# Multi-Column Join in Hibernate/JPA Annotations

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, annotations

I have two entities which I would like to join through multiple columns. These columns are shared by an `@Embeddable` object that is shared by both entities. In the example below, `Foo` can have only one `Bar` but `Bar` can have multiple `Foo`s (where `AnEmbeddableObject` is a unique key for `Bar`). Here is an example:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "foo")
public class Foo {
    @Id
    @Column(name = "id")
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "seqGen")
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "seqGen", sequenceName = "FOO_ID_SEQ", allocationSize = 1)
    private Long id;
    @Embedded
    private AnEmbeddableObject anEmbeddableObject;
    @ManyToOne(targetEntity = Bar.class, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumns( {
        @JoinColumn(name = "column_1", referencedColumnName = "column_1"),
        @JoinColumn(name = "column_2", referencedColumnName = "column_2"),
        @JoinColumn(name = "column_3", referencedColumnName = "column_3"),
        @JoinColumn(name = "column_4", referencedColumnName = "column_4")
    })
    private Bar bar;

    // ... rest of class
}
```

And the Bar class:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "bar")
public class Bar {
    @Id
    @Column(name = "id")
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "seqGen")
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "seqGen", sequenceName = "BAR_ID_SEQ", allocationSize = 1)
    private Long id;
    @Embedded
    private AnEmbeddableObject anEmbeddableObject;

    // ... rest of class
}
```

Finally the `AnEmbeddedObject` class:

```
@Embeddable
public class AnEmbeddedObject {
    @Column(name = "column_1")
    private Long column1;
    @Column(name = "column_2")
    private Long column2;
    @Column(name = "column_3")
    private Long column3;
    @Column(name = "column_4")
    private Long column4;

    // ... rest of class
}
```

Obviously the schema is poorly normalised, it is a restriction that `AnEmbeddedObject`'s fields are repeated in each table.

The problem I have is that I receive this error when I try to start up Hibernate:

```
org.hibernate.AnnotationException: referencedColumnNames(column_1, column_2, column_3, column_4) of Foo.bar referencing Bar not mapped to a single property
```

I have tried marking the JoinColumns are not insertable and updatable, but with no luck. Is there a way to express this with Hibernate/JPA annotations?

Comment: What if you remove the embeddable from `Foo`?

Answer (score 21):

This worked for me . In my case 2 tables foo and boo have to be joined based on 3 different columns.Please note in my case ,in boo the 3 common columns are not primary key

i.e., one to one mapping based on 3 different columns

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "foo")
public class foo implements Serializable
{
    @Column(name="foocol1")
    private String foocol1;
    //add getter setter
    @Column(name="foocol2")
    private String foocol2;
    //add getter setter
    @Column(name="foocol3")
    private String foocol3;
    //add getter setter
    private Boo boo;
    private int id;
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "brsitem_id", updatable = false)
    public int getId()
    {
        return this.id;
    }
    public void setId(int id)
    {
        this.id = id;
    }
    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumns(
    {
        @JoinColumn(updatable=false,insertable=false, name="foocol1", referencedColumnName="boocol1"),
        @JoinColumn(updatable=false,insertable=false, name="foocol2", referencedColumnName="boocol2"),
        @JoinColumn(updatable=false,insertable=false, name="foocol3", referencedColumnName="boocol3")
    }
    )
    public Boo getBoo()
    {
        return boo;
    }
    public void setBoo(Boo boo)
    {
        this.boo = boo;
    }
}





@Entity
@Table(name = "boo")
public class Boo implements Serializable
{
    private int id;
    @Column(name="boocol1")
    private String boocol1;
    //add getter setter
    @Column(name="boocol2")
    private String boocol2;
    //add getter setter
    @Column(name="boocol3")
    private String boocol3;
    //add getter setter
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "item_id", updatable = false)
    public int getId()
    {
        return id;
    }
    public void setId(int id)
    {
        this.id = id;
    }
}
```

Comment: In my case i want to join on one column but the deleted field should be null in order to make the join (i dont want to retrieve softly deleted items) how to implement this?

Answer (score 14):

If this doesn't work I'm out of ideas. This way you get the 4 columns in both tables (as `Bar` owns them and `Foo` uses them to reference `Bar`) and the generated IDs in both entities. The set of 4 columns has to be unique in `Bar` so the many-to-one relation doesn't become a many-to-many.

```
@Embeddable
public class AnEmbeddedObject
{
    @Column(name = "column_1")
    private Long column1;
    @Column(name = "column_2")
    private Long column2;
    @Column(name = "column_3")
    private Long column3;
    @Column(name = "column_4")
    private Long column4;
}

@Entity
public class Foo
{
    @Id
    @Column(name = "id")
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "seqGen")
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "seqGen", sequenceName = "FOO_ID_SEQ", allocationSize = 1)
    private Long id;
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumns({
        @JoinColumn(name = "column_1", referencedColumnName = "column_1"),
        @JoinColumn(name = "column_2", referencedColumnName = "column_2"),
        @JoinColumn(name = "column_3", referencedColumnName = "column_3"),
        @JoinColumn(name = "column_4", referencedColumnName = "column_4")
    })
    private Bar bar;
}

@Entity
@Table(uniqueConstraints = @UniqueConstraint(columnNames = {
    "column_1",
    "column_2",
    "column_3",
    "column_4"
}))
public class Bar
{
    @Id
    @Column(name = "id")
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "seqGen")
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "seqGen", sequenceName = "BAR_ID_SEQ", allocationSize = 1)
    private Long id;
    @Embedded
    private AnEmbeddedObject anEmbeddedObject;
}
```

Comment: That's the rub, the "AnEmbeddedObject" must exist in both objects. The generated id is preferable for performance reasons.

Comment: So the 4 columns plus the generated key map to bar? That is very very bad. If your solution is to generate a surrogate key for `Bar` and don't make the columns in `Foo` foreign key, you have to set the columns in `Foo` yourself. If I'm right I can  adjust my answer. ;-)

Comment: @bowsie I modified my answer so `Foo` and `Bar` both have the 4 columns and `Bar` is referenced in `Foo` with its ID.

Comment: Cheers. But this is still not quite what I'm after. For performance reasons I do not want to look up Bar's primary id, and I expect that hibernate should allow me to join on whatever I want - and if I do reference columns twice then setting insertable and updatable to false should do the trick - like with single-column joins.

Comment: @bowsie I've adjusted my answer again, maybe this is what you are looking for?

Comment: Looking at the answer in 2020 , the code looks horrible.  Can someone please explain why should we use JPA if  we have multiple and complex joins. Why not Spring jdbc or any other ORM ?  Just want to understand.  Also let's say I have 10 joins in a query and multiple such queries ,  the whole class will be filled with annotations.

Answer (score 5):

Hibernate is not going to make it easy for you to do what you are trying to do. From the [Hibernate documentation](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/annotations/3.5/reference/en/html_single/#d0e1591):

> Note that when using referencedColumnName to a non primary key column, the associated class has to be Serializable. ***Also note that the referencedColumnName to a non primary key column has to be mapped to a property having a single column (other cases might not work).*** *(emphasis added)*

So if you are unwilling to make `AnEmbeddableObject` the Identifier for Bar then Hibernate is not going to lazily, automatically retrieve Bar for you.  You can, of course, still use HQL to write queries that join on `AnEmbeddableObject`, but you lose automatic fetching and life cycle maintenance if you insist on using  a multi-column non-primary key for Bar.

Comment: I'd say it's worth a shot, in theory using multiple foreign keys which refer to one unique constraint should be possible. If it's not the OP's out of luck. +1 for this is possibly the answer.

Comment: @siebz0r, the OP has taken the shot and gotten almost exactly the error message I would expect for this error condition:  "referencedColumnNames... ***not mapped to a single property***".  It should say "not mapped to a property having a single column," but it's about the same thing.

Comment: I guess it's game over then ;-)

Comment: Thanks for the info. I have been using HQL in the meantime - but good to understand the limitations. +1